# Is it too soon to leave my job if I just started?

Tags: job-offer, career-development, new-job, quitting

I worked at a reputable national company for over a year in hopes of joining an international agency. My salary did not change between the two jobs when I made the switch one month ago, but I was looking for more challenges and my old company couldn't offer me growth. I was ecstatic to be accepted at this huge international agency, but the job IS NOT what was pitched in my interview. They also called me the same day of my interview to offer me the job and I could barely get a day to think about the offer. I'm of a very creative mindset and this job is mainly excel, emails, and crunching numbers. The agency is amazing, but I've only been here for a month and I feel as though I've made a huge mistake.

I'm in the interview process with another national company that has a salary raise, higher title, and is more creative. If they do offer me the job should I take it in hopes that this will be a job I can spend time in? I'm worried I'll become a job hopper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If they do offer me the job should I take it in hopes that this will
>   be a job I can spend time in? I'm worried I'll become a job hopper.

If you leave after a month, you are hopping. If you do this repeatedly, then you are a job hopper.

But it's always the next employer who gets to judge how much importance to place on the duration of your prior jobs. Some employers wouldn't like to see a 1-month exit. Others wouldn't care.

As far as if you should take this job - you should do what feels right to you. Try to make sure this job is a "keeper" *before* you accept it this time.

Answer (score 5):

It is never too soon to leave a job - that is exactly what the probation period is all about, determining whether you are actually a good fit for the position the company wishes you to fill, and whether the position is a good fit for your expectations.

You can find yourself leaving a brand new position for any number of reasons, and "job not matching what was pitched" is a valid one.  If you are asked by a new employer during an interview, just tell the truth - the position wasn't for you once you had tried to settle in, mainly because it wasn't on the basis of what you accepted the offer.

You don't become a job hopper through one or two events in your employment history - it takes several events, so just make sure that you know exactly what you are going into next time.  Ask more questions at the interview.  Don't be afraid of asking questions after you get the offer (but don't accept until you get answers).

Comment: @JoeStrazzere that is true, there is an assumption there.  But I would still personally class the first 3 months as a probationary period if I were ever hired in the US - you simply don't know enough about the company until you start working there.  The job may be perfect, but your co-workers may be santa worshipers and every day may be a chore.  No way to determine that until you actually get the job (bar tracking down past employees, obviously).

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I didnt want to raise the ire of a mod, so it was deliberate ;) .  As I said, "I would still *personally* class..." - its a personal decision, those first few months give me information I could never get without working there, and I would approach that the same as I would as if I were in a probationary period here in the UK.  If I didn't like the company, I would have no ethical issues with leaving in those first few months.  I generally stay with a company for several years, and my only short stint was for reasons I wouldnt have got from an interview (they couldnt pay employees)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere in the UK, its the same, regardless of there being a probationary period.  If you have several short periods, something is wrong and flags are raised on that application.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere but the emphasis is on *several* short periods.  A couple in a career wouldnt raise any flags at all - several indicates that either the candidate isnt a good judge of character, or something else is going on.  As its so hard to get rid of an employee here (its got easier in the first 2 years recently, but still...) its best not to hire them in the first place.